# Java Garbage Collection Behavior for Many Short-Lived Objects

Tags: java, scala, garbage-collection, apache-kafka

I have a Java process that allocates a lot of very short-lived objects (measured using YourKit to have average age between 10-20 ms), and very few long lasting objects, and its function is to accept a TCP message, transform it in some way, and produce to Kafka.

The majority of the objects are created by the Kafka producer that is written in Scala and consequently uses a lot of immutable objects. Again using YourKit, I've measured that the size of the immutable objects from Kafka is around 75% of the total, and the number of objects from Kafka is around 53% of the total. The vast majority of these objects do not make it past 20 ms.

In an attempt to optimize my application for this use case, I have tried to tune the garbage collector so that it recognizes the short-lived objects as the common use case, and discards of the majority before it reaches the old gen. Here are the knobs I have used so far:

```
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps \
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution \
-XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:NewRatio=1 \
```

The most important flags are `-XX:NewRatio` and `-XX:UseParallelOldGC` but I am noticing some strange behavior in the GC patterns.

Here's an illustration of the heap usage before the first full GC:
[image: Heap Usage Transient State]

Here's an illustration of the steady state heap usage:[image: Heap Usage Steady State]

As you can see, the tenuring is happening very slowly (I also confirmed this using the heap information printed after each gc) before the first full GC, but after the first full GC, the tenuring starts happening very quickly.

I don't understand the reason for this, and I find the full GCs completely unnecessary - the full GC causes almost the entire heap to be reclaimed because the vast vast majority of objects have already lost their strong reference.

If it would help to include the heap information after each GC, I will do so, but for now, this should be sufficient information.

If anyone has any idea why this could be happening, please let me know. A full GC an hour seems too frequent for such an application.

EDIT:

As requested, here is some additional information:

- I am using Java 7, version 1.7.0_51.
- I have allocated 1 GB of memory for this process, and the heap has been fixed at this size.
- Some heap output from minor GCs before the first full GC:

> ```
> {Heap before GC invocations=395 (full 0):
>  PSYoungGen      total 521728K, used 519744K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
>   eden space 518656K, 100% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ffa80000,0x00000000ffa80000)
>   from space 3072K, 35% used [0x00000000ffd00000,0x00000000ffe10000,0x0000000100000000)
>   to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ffa80000,0x00000000ffa80000,0x00000000ffd00000)
>  ParOldGen       total 524288K, used 177521K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e0000000)
>   object space 524288K, 33% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cad5c560,0x00000000e0000000)
>  PSPermGen       total 33280K, used 33132K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000bce80000, 0x00000000c0000000)
>   object space 33280K, 99% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bce5b3d0,0x00000000bce80000)
> 35744.334: [GC
> Desired survivor size 2621440 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 15)
>  [PSYoungGen: 519744K->1184K(521216K)] 697265K->179113K(1045504K), 0.0039310 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
> Heap after GC invocations=395 (full 0):
>  PSYoungGen      total 521216K, used 1184K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
>   eden space 518656K, 0% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ffa80000)
>   from space 2560K, 46% used [0x00000000ffa80000,0x00000000ffba8000,0x00000000ffd00000)
>   to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ffd80000,0x00000000ffd80000,0x0000000100000000)
>  ParOldGen       total 524288K, used 177929K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e0000000)
>   object space 524288K, 33% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000cadc2560,0x00000000e0000000)
>  PSPermGen       total 33280K, used 33132K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000bce80000, 0x00000000c0000000)
>   object space 33280K, 99% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bce5b3d0,0x00000000bce80000)
> }
> ```

- The heap output of the first Full GC:

> ```
> {Heap before GC invocations=1457 (full 0):
>  PSYoungGen      total 521728K, used 520064K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
>   eden space 519168K, 100% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ffb00000,0x00000000ffb00000)
>   from space 2560K, 35% used [0x00000000ffd80000,0x00000000ffe60000,0x0000000100000000)
>   to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ffb00000,0x00000000ffb00000,0x00000000ffd80000)
>  ParOldGen       total 524288K, used 523194K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e0000000)
>   object space 524288K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000dfeeea68,0x00000000e0000000)
>  PSPermGen       total 34304K, used 34213K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000bcf80000, 0x00000000c0000000)
>   object space 34304K, 99% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bcf695e8,0x00000000bcf80000)
> 99997.829: [GC
> Desired survivor size 2621440 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 15)
>  [PSYoungGen: 520064K->1600K(521728K)] 1043258K->525386K(1046016K), 0.0072540 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]
> Heap after GC invocations=1457 (full 0):
>  PSYoungGen      total 521728K, used 1600K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
>   eden space 519168K, 0% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ffb00000)
>   from space 2560K, 62% used [0x00000000ffb00000,0x00000000ffc90000,0x00000000ffd80000)
>   to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ffd80000,0x00000000ffd80000,0x0000000100000000)
>  ParOldGen       total 524288K, used 523786K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e0000000)
>   object space 524288K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000dff82a68,0x00000000e0000000)
>  PSPermGen       total 34304K, used 34213K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000bcf80000, 0x00000000c0000000)
>   object space 34304K, 99% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bcf695e8,0x00000000bcf80000)
> }
> {Heap before GC invocations=1458 (full 1):
>  PSYoungGen      total 521728K, used 1600K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
>   eden space 519168K, 0% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ffb00000)
>   from space 2560K, 62% used [0x00000000ffb00000,0x00000000ffc90000,0x00000000ffd80000)
>   to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ffd80000,0x00000000ffd80000,0x0000000100000000)
>  ParOldGen       total 524288K, used 523786K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e0000000)
>   object space 524288K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000dff82a68,0x00000000e0000000)
>  PSPermGen       total 34304K, used 34213K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000bcf80000, 0x00000000c0000000)
>   object space 34304K, 99% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bcf695e8,0x00000000bcf80000)
> 99997.837: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 1600K->0K(521728K)] [ParOldGen: 523786K->17123K(524288K)] 525386K->17123K(1046016K) [PSPermGen: 34213K->33877K(68096K)], 0.1576350 secs] [Times: user=0.53 sys=0.03, real=0.16 secs]
> Heap after GC invocations=1458 (full 1):
>  PSYoungGen      total 521728K, used 0K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
>   eden space 519168K, 0% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ffb00000)
>   from space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ffb00000,0x00000000ffb00000,0x00000000ffd80000)
>   to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ffd80000,0x00000000ffd80000,0x0000000100000000)
>  ParOldGen       total 524288K, used 17123K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e0000000)
>   object space 524288K, 3% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c10b8fc8,0x00000000e0000000)
>  PSPermGen       total 68096K, used 33877K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000bf080000, 0x00000000c0000000)
>   object space 68096K, 49% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bcf156f0,0x00000000bf080000)
> }
> ```

- The heap output of a minor collection after the first Full GC has occurred:

> ```
>  {Heap before GC invocations=1837 (full 9):
>   PSYoungGen      total 509440K, used 507104K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
>    eden space 494592K, 100% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000fe300000,0x00000000fe300000)
>    from space 14848K, 84% used [0x00000000fe300000,0x00000000fef38000,0x00000000ff180000)
>    to   space 14848K, 0% used [0x00000000ff180000,0x00000000ff180000,0x0000000100000000)
>   ParOldGen       total 524288K, used 342941K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e0000000)
>    object space 524288K, 65% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000d4ee7520,0x00000000e0000000)
>   PSPermGen       total 54272K, used 33876K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000be300000, 0x00000000c0000000)
>    object space 54272K, 62% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bcf15378,0x00000000be300000)
>  133247.303: [GC
>  Desired survivor size 15204352 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 15)
>   [PSYoungGen: 507104K->13696K(509440K)] 850045K->369421K(1033728K), 0.0318090 secs] [Times: user=0.37 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs]
>  Heap after GC invocations=1837 (full 9):
>   PSYoungGen      total 509440K, used 13696K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
>    eden space 494592K, 0% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000fe300000)
>    from space 14848K, 92% used [0x00000000ff180000,0x00000000ffee0000,0x0000000100000000)
>    to   space 14848K, 0% used [0x00000000fe300000,0x00000000fe300000,0x00000000ff180000)
>   ParOldGen       total 524288K, used 355725K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e0000000)
>    object space 524288K, 67% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000d5b63520,0x00000000e0000000)
>   PSPermGen       total 54272K, used 33876K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000be300000, 0x00000000c0000000)
>    object space 54272K, 62% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bcf15378,0x00000000be300000)
>  }
> ```

- The heap output of a full GC after the first:

> ```
> {Heap before GC invocations=1457 (full 0):
>  PSYoungGen      total 521728K, used 520064K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
>   eden space 519168K, 100% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ffb00000,0x00000000ffb00000)
>   from space 2560K, 35% used [0x00000000ffd80000,0x00000000ffe60000,0x0000000100000000)
>   to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ffb00000,0x00000000ffb00000,0x00000000ffd80000)
>  ParOldGen       total 524288K, used 523194K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e0000000)
>   object space 524288K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000dfeeea68,0x00000000e0000000)
>  PSPermGen       total 34304K, used 34213K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000bcf80000, 0x00000000c0000000)
>   object space 34304K, 99% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bcf695e8,0x00000000bcf80000)
> 99997.829: [GC
> Desired survivor size 2621440 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 15)
>  [PSYoungGen: 520064K->1600K(521728K)] 1043258K->525386K(1046016K), 0.0072540 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]
> Heap after GC invocations=1457 (full 0):
>  PSYoungGen      total 521728K, used 1600K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
>   eden space 519168K, 0% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ffb00000)
>   from space 2560K, 62% used [0x00000000ffb00000,0x00000000ffc90000,0x00000000ffd80000)
>   to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ffd80000,0x00000000ffd80000,0x0000000100000000)
>  ParOldGen       total 524288K, used 523786K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e0000000)
>   object space 524288K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000dff82a68,0x00000000e0000000)
>  PSPermGen       total 34304K, used 34213K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000bcf80000, 0x00000000c0000000)
>   object space 34304K, 99% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bcf695e8,0x00000000bcf80000)
> }
> {Heap before GC invocations=1458 (full 1):
>  PSYoungGen      total 521728K, used 1600K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
>   eden space 519168K, 0% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ffb00000)
>   from space 2560K, 62% used [0x00000000ffb00000,0x00000000ffc90000,0x00000000ffd80000)
>   to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ffd80000,0x00000000ffd80000,0x0000000100000000)
>  ParOldGen       total 524288K, used 523786K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e0000000)
>   object space 524288K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000dff82a68,0x00000000e0000000)
>  PSPermGen       total 34304K, used 34213K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000bcf80000, 0x00000000c0000000)
>   object space 34304K, 99% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bcf695e8,0x00000000bcf80000)
> 99997.837: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 1600K->0K(521728K)] [ParOldGen: 523786K->17123K(524288K)] 525386K->17123K(1046016K) [PSPermGen: 34213K->33877K(68096K)], 0.1576350 secs] [Times: user=0.53 sys=0.03, real=0.16 secs]
> Heap after GC invocations=1458 (full 1):
>  PSYoungGen      total 521728K, used 0K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
>   eden space 519168K, 0% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000ffb00000)
>   from space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ffb00000,0x00000000ffb00000,0x00000000ffd80000)
>   to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ffd80000,0x00000000ffd80000,0x0000000100000000)
>  ParOldGen       total 524288K, used 17123K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e0000000)
>   object space 524288K, 3% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c10b8fc8,0x00000000e0000000)
>  PSPermGen       total 68096K, used 33877K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000bf080000, 0x00000000c0000000)
>   object space 68096K, 49% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bcf156f0,0x00000000bf080000)
> }
> ```

Comment: It looks like too many objects are promoted from the young generation to the old. This could be for a number of reasons but without a GC log it's difficult to tell.

Comment: It may be helpful to specify exactly which version of the JVM you are using.

Comment: you should attach/pastebin GC logs. Also, you're dealing with the *throughput collector*, it's configured to maximize throughput by default and thus trading a little more major GC time for less expensive minor GCs may be a trade-off that it ends up making to meet that goal.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that GC tuning is the right way to solve your problem?  A significant fraction of support cases that my organization deals with are caused by a customer turning a knob that they ought not to have turned, in an attempt to solve a "problem" that either could have been solved in a better way or, was only an imagined problem in the first place.

Comment: It would be nice to put some actual numbers to it too: how many transactions per second, what size of memory are we talking about? For all we know, a full GC every hour can even be normal for what you're doing. Another question is: what kind of problems are you experiencing? What do you try to optimise for?

Comment: I've added additional information as requested. 
@jameslarge I totally agree with you, but I want to know if that's the situation mine is in. I am purely basing this on my knowledge about Full GCs and the object allocation pattern of my application. It's a gut feeling that tenuring is unnecessary and since clearing the old gen takes longer than the young gen, it makes sense to optimize.

Comment: @biziclop The current application is handling around 200-300 requests/sec, which is not much at all. My expectation is to be able to handle the maximum requests per second that I can squeeze, without running into throughput issues due to GC. I have not scale tested it at much higher rates but other sample points show that the full GC period decreases linearly with higher request rates.

Comment: What jumps out from the logs is a tenuring threshold of 1, which means that objects survive only one minor GC in the survivor spaces and the next time around they are booted into the old generation. This threshold value seems suspiciously low given that the default is around 6 (and as you can see, the current maximum is 15). As an experiment you can try setting the `-XX:+NeverTenure` flag just to see what happens. (It's incredibly rare that this flag does anything but harm, so I wouldn't recommend it in production.)

Comment: There's also the  `-XX:InitialTenuringThreshold=<x>` option to set the starting threshold but that only gives you a starting value, the JVM is free to adjust it up/down adaptively. While you're doing these experiments, check the tenuring distribution to see if your changes have the desired effect.

Comment: @biziclop Right, I've tried the `-XX:InitialTenuringThreshold` option before to no avail. It just settles right back down to 1. Another option I've considered is setting the maximum survivor space size, but it seems heavy handed. I'm also cautious about the survivor ratio setting because it's a convex curve with an optimal area and I don't know what the sweet spot is without an egregious amount of data gathering and I'm hesitant to go that route.

Comment: Okay, next thing to look at is `-XX:NewRatio=1`, I'm not sure committing half of the entire heap to the new generation helps you. A ratio of 3 sounds more reasonable. After that, there's the matter of the survivor spaces being about 0.5% the size of eden. Setting a `MinSurvivorRatio` of 8 would bring them up to 10%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only Full GC in your log <sup>[seriously, is it too hard to post a log somwhere without butchering it?]</sup> takes about 160ms, the minor GCs take 30ms or less.

You are not setting any pause time goals.

One or more *hours* pass between full GCs.

If you are under the impression that full GCs are somehow "evil" and must be avoided under all costs, then you are wrong.

They can be troublesome with CMS because with CMS the Full GCs are a *failure-mode* single-threaded fallback strategy which can take very long on large heaps.

But you're using the Parallel Old Gen collector, aka *throughput collector* on a small heap, where a full GC is very fast, especially when most of the old gen contents are garbage that does not have to be visited by the mark-sweep algorithm.

And considering that you haven't even specified a pause time goal or tried CMS suggests to me that you don't even have a well-defined goal for them.

So there is no problem here.

Comment: I don't understand how I butchered adding the gc log here. If you have formatting suggestions, say so in the comments or better yet, edit the question. Including your condescension in an answer isn't productive. I'm new here, and including code snippets in a list isn't straightforward: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item.

Comment: GC logs can be many megabytes in size, they cannot be directly included in a SO question. The - in my opinion obvious - solution to provide them verbatim is to upload them somewhere else. pastebin, github or similar.

Comment: Your "obvious" point is noted. Thanks for answering the question.